# Request_ResourceNotFound in azure issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, onedrive

I am trying to upload document to OneDrive through my application. When i am trying to login Onedrive i am getting below error message.

```
(1002144-A1) Onedrive upload failed with exception:
Code: Request_ResourceNotFound
Message: Resource 'demo@domain.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

My application is a multitenant application. Can anyone have an idea about this issue.

Comment: Does this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/aad-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online?

Answer (score 0):

•   You are getting this error because the **required scopes and the permissions for the Azure AD app registration are not correct as well as there might be query formatting errors in your ‘Onedrive’ request from your application**. For that purpose, kindly ensure the below settings are configured aptly in your application: -

a)  Client ID and Key (client secret) as registered with Azure Active Directory (AAD)

b)  Authorization code received from OAuth 2 authorization code flow

c)  OneDrive for Business API endpoint URL

d)  Access token for the OneDrive for Business resource

e)  Refresh token to generate additional access tokens when the current token expires.

Thus, follow the steps as shown in the manner as above. Kindly get an authorization code as below: -

```
  GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&scope={scope}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
```

Then **ensure to redeem the code for access tokens as below upon successful authentication and authorization** wherein the response will be as below: -

Response: -

```
 https://myapp.com/auth-redirect?code=df6aa589-1080-b241-b410-c4dff65dbf7c
```

Redeem the code for access tokens as below: -

```
   POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

   client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={client_secret}
   &code={code}&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Then, further **get a new access token or refresh token as below wherein the response** should be as follows: -

Refresh token redemption: -

```
 POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&client_secret={client_secret}
 &refresh_token={refresh_token}&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Response: -

```
{
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "scope": "wl.basic onedrive.readwrite wl.offline_access",
  "access_token":"EwCo...AA==",
  "refresh_token":"eyJh...9323"
}
```

As you can see above, **upon successful authentication via Microsoft Graph as the orchestrator, you get the refresh token, access token and the valid scopes for it too**. Also, please find the below snapshot which shows the scopes required for this: -

[image: Azure AD app required scopes]

Also, do ensure that the **application as an entity exists in the Azure AD app registration for the authentication to Onedrive API to happen** as below: -

[image: MS Graph application search query]

For more detailed information, kindly refer the below links: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/graph-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online***

***https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3539***